# How can I make the original Dwarf Fortress tileset square?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have already gotten used to the default tileset of Dwarf Fortress, so I do not wish to change it a *lot*. That is exactly what most Dwarf Fortress tilesets do, though.

My problem with the default tileset is that it is taller than it is wide, which makes things seem taller than they really are. Is there any way to make the tiles square instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as "Not Constructive" doorknob. You're basically just asking for a list of suggestions, which falls under the "bad subjective" question types and doesn't work well on our site.

Comment: I'd recommend re-wording it to something like, "How can I make the original tileset more square?".  That way, you're not precluding alternate solutions, while still allowing tilesets as solutions.

Comment: @Wipqozn Alright, I changed it a bit to make it a little less N/C. (I know you can't undo your closevote though, that's annoyed me many times :P)

Comment: @fbueckert Done :)

Comment: Hey, it's Doorknob! Didn't think I'd see you outside PPCG!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dwarf fortress already has a square tileset available to you. Simply access your DF graphics folder and copy the name of the square tileset. Then search either init text files (in the DF folder) for the tileset option (it'll have the base tileset name so you could copy that files name from the graphics folder to accelerate your search). Once you've found it, replace the existing entry with the name of the square tileset and voila, original DF look with square tiles.

Comment: Which folder? I'm guessing `/data/art`? (+1)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that - much easier than faffing around with modified tilesets

Comment: I'm not sure which folder, just look around... it isn't hard. Whilst youre fiddling around in the files, you could disable the annoying birth pause and center. =)

Answer (score 8):

The posted tilesets are good, but they are pretty large to someone used to the default tileset and don't scale smaller well. I would recommend [Alloy](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tileset_repository#Alloy). I initially ran into problems getting the transparency  to work, but opening an re-saving the image seems to fix the issue. I've uploaded my fixed version of the file.

[image]

It seems to be basically identical to the default tileset, but with stuff edited to be 12x12 instead of the default 8x12 or the packaged square's 16x16.

To install it, just download the above image, from there or from the wiki, save it as `...\data\art\Alloy_curses_12x12.png`, and replace the lines in `...\data\init\init.txt` that say `[FONT:curses_640x300.png]` and `[FULLFONT:curses_640x300.png]`, lines 30 and 39 as of version 0.34.11, with `[FONT:Alloy_curses_12x12.png]` `[FULLFONT:Alloy_curses_12x12.png]`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are, take a look here

[Tileset repository - Square tilesets](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tileset_repository#Square_tilesets)

Comment: That's a lot of tilesets! Which one is the closest to the original tileset?

Comment: @Doorknob I'm not sure, I don't play with the original tileset so I don't remember what they look like

Comment: Sappho description from that page says "Another square font, target resolution 1280×400. This one is exactly the same as the default font except it has been made square, painstakingly edited to ensure that nothing looks squished."